# How to do a login verification

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

I am creating a system in nodejs + mongodb but I am having difficulty checking if the email and password match.

this is the function that sends the parameters to the api:

```
function log(e){
e.preventDefault();
let email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
let password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
let loginstatus = document.querySelector('#loginstatus');

fetch('http://localhost:3000/userV', { method: 'post', headers: {Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify({
  email: email,
  senha: password
})
}).then((resp) => {
if(resp.status == 200){


}else{
  loginstatus.textContent = 'Usuario ou senha incorretos!';
  loginstatus.style.color = 'red';
}
}).catch((err) => {
alert("Ouve um erro no servidor.\nErro:"+err);
});}
```

here is where it should be doing the verification but always returns "yes", what is wrong in my form? would you have another recommended way to do it?

```
async index(req, res) {
    let reqemail = req.params.email;
    let reqsenha = req.params.senha;

    const users = await Users.find({ email: reqemail });

    if(reqsenha == users.senha){
        return res.send('yes')
    }else{
        return res.send('no')
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only checking the `resp.status` (200), not the content of the response (yes/no).

Comment: @TGrif as well? 
he should be comparing the password that was received with the one he sought in the bank

Comment: As welll, you could also `console.log()` the value of reqesenha and user.senha to figure it out why it returns always `true`.